# Symbol.species example from MDN not making sense?

Tags: javascript

I was just translating an article about [Symbol.species](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/species) in MDN, when I stumpled upon the following section:

> You might want to return Array objects in your derived array class MyArray. For example, when using methods such as map() that return the default constructor, you want these methods to return a parent Array object, instead of the MyArray object. The species symbol lets you do this:
>
> ```
> class MyArray extends Array {
>   // Overwrite species to the parent Array constructor
>   static get [Symbol.species]() { return Array; }
>   }
> var a = new MyArray(1,2,3);
> var mapped = a.map(x => x * x);
> console.log(mapped instanceof MyArray); // false
> console.log(mapped instanceof Array);   // true
> ```

Beside having trouble to translate the text, which didn't give me the feeling to know what's going on, the code doesn't prove their point. When I comment out the line `static get [Symbol.species]() { return Array; }` the result is exactly the same.

Here's my code:

```
"use strict";

class MyArray extends Array {
  // Overwrite species to the parent Array constructor
  // static get [Symbol.species]() { return Array; }
}
var a = new MyArray(1,2,3);
var mapped = a.map(x => x * x);

console.log(mapped instanceof MyArray); // false
console.log(mapped instanceof Array);   // true
```

And my console output:

```
➜ node test.js
false
true
```

Is that article simply wrong, or am I, as a JS/Node beginner, missing an important detail?

Comment: FYI, I just tried your example code in latest Chrome, Firefox and node.js and they all log 'true' twice, i.e. they conform with the MDN example.

Comment: The MDN article is still the same and it still sucks. It really needs explain (or link out to) what exactly is happening. In its current state, its a bit magical ... "Do this and it works!" What does species mean? Is it kind of like an interface? Whats up with the square bracket syntax? Too many questions. Poor documentation.

Comment: I wrote a blog post with some examples on `Symbol.species` here: http://jsbits-yo.com/snippet/symbols-are-your-friend-party-iv-symbol-search-symbol-split-symbol-species

Comment: @docta_faustus The link you provided didn't work, [here](http://jsbits-yo.com/snippet/symbols-are-your-friend-part-iv-symbol-search-symbol-split-symbol-species-js-bits-4i25) is the correct one.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are missing an important detail. If you subclass array, and then do a `map`, using Symbol.species you can get back an *array*, not a member of your derived class. Sometimes you want that, for instance if you are exposing an API as a library author. You may want some special subclass sauce for your internal use but expose methods that return regular arrays for public consumption.

And there's no real limit, you can set up an alternate constructor for anything at all.

As for why commenting out the line doesn't change anything, remember that subclassing built-ins is new, may not be fully and correctly implemented, and that this is especially true with node.js where if they jump on the bandwagon early they get stuck supporting something 'wrong' for years in an LTS (they got burned on that on [Object.observe](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/an-update-on-object-observe)).

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't really understand. Let's assume we want to generate MyArray objects with `map`, how would I go for that? I will definitely keep on digging to make sure I can judge if your answer is correct...

Comment: @Flip getting back your subclass is the default, i.e. `myArray.map(someFn)` will return an instance of myArray. Sometimes you will want to override this (like the library author example I gave above). This is more important for host implemented methods like `Array.prototype.map`, for custom methods you'd just override it in the subclass. But with Symbol.species you can (theoretically) get the speed boost of `map` being implemented in C++ rather than JavaScript.

Comment: Alright, I will read about the difference between host implemented methods and custom methods, and accept your answer. Thanks for staying with me!

Comment: @Flip no problem. As for 'host implemented' methods, I just mean ones that JavaScript gives you out of the box instead of ones that you authored. They aren't necessarily implemented in JS, they are frequently implemented in the (much faster) host language, which for most JavaScript engines is C++. Remember that JS runs on a VM like V8, it doesn't compile down to native code directly.

Answer (score 7):

> When I comment out the line `static get [Symbol.species]() { return Array; }` the result is exactly the same.

**In a correct implementation of ES6 it wouldn't be the same!**

For anyone looking for more examples, [this article](https://www.keithcirkel.co.uk/metaprogramming-in-es6-symbols/#symbolspecies) from Keith Cirkel (*keithamus* on [Github](https://github.com/keithamus)) does a lot more at exlaining the concept than the MDN docs.

---

And here is an excerpt (emphasis mine):

> "Now, if you were to make a `class Foo extends Array` - every time you called `Foo#map` **while before it would return an Array (no fun)** and you’d have to write your own Map implementation just to create `Foo`s instead of `Array`s, **now `Foo#map` return a `Foo`**, thanks to `Symbol.species`"

Comment: But is this not the opposite of what the MDN example shows? The MDN example says: 
> For example, when using methods such as map() that return the default constructor, you want these methods to return a parent Array object, instead of the MyArray object.

Comment: (Posting this since can't edit earlier comment):
But the MDN example says: 
> For example, when using methods such as map() that return the default constructor, you want these methods to return a parent Array object, instead of the MyArray object. 

So, according to MDN, every time you call Foo#map, be default it is supposed to return a Foo, not an ordinary Array. Now, I actually agree with what you wrote above (normally with OOP, inherited methods return types remain the same in derived classes), but then that means the MDN explanation is wrong, unless I'm missing something.